# Whats the best way to build a scheduler that query the database everyday and sends out notifications?

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, logic, backend

So I have three databases and all of them have some data with different dates.
I want to send notifications at those particular dates every month.

I was thinking of creating a cron which runs daily and it would query the table everyday and if date in the table matches today's date then it would send a notification

I am not sure if its the efficient way to do that.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you mean by dates. Is this like 1st of the month 15th of the month? Also what is you date format and database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of *"query the table everyday and if date in the table matches today's date then it would send a notification"* is accurate.

The main choice is whether you wish to do this on an Amazon EC2 instance or with AWS Lambda.

#### Amazon EC2

It appears that you wish to send notifications once per day. If so, then you could activate an Amazon EC2 instance once per day, do the necessary work, then stop the instance. This way, you are only paying for the time that the instance is actually doing work:

- Create an Amazon CloudWatch Events Rule that runs an AWS Lambda function at a given time each day
- The **Lambda function** would issue a `StartInstance()` command to activate the EC2 instance
- A script on the instance would activate upon startup and do the daily processing
- At the end of the script, it issues a shutdown command to turn off the instance

For configuration details, see: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

The benefit of this approach is that there are no time limits. The Amazon EC2 instance is quite low cost if only running it once per day.

#### AWS Lambda

An AWS Lambda function could do the same task, but it is limited to a maximum runtime of 15 minutes. If it is likely that the daily task might take longer than 15 minutes, it could be further subdivided:

- An initial **AWS Lambda function** (triggered by Amazon CloudWatch Events) that queries the database to identify users to contact
- The Lambda function can push messages into an **Amazon SQS queue** for each piece of work required
- Another **AWS Lambda function** can be configured to trigger off the Amazon SQS queue, which notifies the user identified in the message. This Lambda function can run in parallel, so messages will be sent out quickly.

#### Database

It sounds like you already have a database. I would recommend the following flow:

- The script (either on EC2 or Lambda) does a database SELECT to retrieve all users who wish to be notified, where the `last_notification` (see below) is prior to the desired notification date
- The script then notifies each user (as per above options)
- The database records are updated so that `last_notification` is set to `NOW()`

This way, if the script does not run every day, or if there is an error, the system will know which users need to be notified. This is better than assuming that the script will successfully run each day.

#### Frequency

If your functionality actually requires notifications **at a particular time** (not just a particular day), then the script would need to run more often than once per day.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your "databases" are actually a structured files, not real databases.  (You don't parse a real database.)

I am also assuming that they are large; i.e tens of thousands of records or more.)  If they are small then the overhead of parsing a file is too small to be concerned about.

Based on those assumptions, the most efficient way (in terms of processing time) is to keep your data in a real database and use database queries to extract the data that pertain to each day.

On the other hand, if the databases don't qualify as large, the best way is the simple way ... for you to implement.

Comment: sorry english is not my first language, and yes they are real databases with some what large data in them

Comment: In that case, I don't know what you are even asking.  Just query them.  Why do you think it would be inefficient?